# Error while using css-b64-images on jquery ui css: ENAMETOOLONG

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-ui, base64

I'm using css-b64-images to base 64 my images in a css file. Since we're using an old version of jquery-ui I updated to the latest version. Problem is that now the css-b64-images fails on the jquery-ui.css (1.11.4):

```
[ { [Error: ENOENT, stat 'build/data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP/yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7']
    errno: 34,
    code: 'ENOENT',
    path: 'build/data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP/yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7' },
  { [Error: ENAMETOOLONG, stat 'build/data:image/gif;base64,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']
    errno: 49,
    code: 'ENAMETOOLONG',
    path: 'build/data:image/gif;base64,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' } ]
```

After investigating a bit it seems that the issue is that 2 of the image from the jquery-ui.css are already in base 64 while the rest are given by path. I'm not sure how to proceed to get around this.

Example of url's from the jquery-ui.css:

```
url("data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7");
```

or

```
url("../assets/jqueryui/ui-bg_gloss-wave_35_f6a828_500x100.png") 50% 50% repeat-x;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This was an issue with css-b64-images, updated on github.